# JSON.stringify of object of map return empty

Tags: javascript, json

```
    var map1= new Map();
    map1.set("one",1);
    var map2 = new Map();
    map2.set("two",2);
   concatMap = {};
   concatMap['one']= map1;
   concatMap['two']= map2;
 JSON.stringify(concatMap);
```

> //outputs : "{"one":{},"two":{}}"
>
> I also tried:

```
concatMap = {};
concatMap.one= map1;
concatMap.two= map2;
```

why am I getting the empty object instead of map 1 and map 2 when I use JSON.stringify()?

Comment: I think JSON.stringify does not yet support Maps. I would try `concatMap.one = [...map1]`

Comment: Also note if you have a numerical key, object would seem to be empty.

Comment: instead of adding properties to the Map object, you can normally just create an array from 'map.entries' and then stringify the array as normal (see my answer below for details)

Answer (score 14):

This is the expected result. `JSON.stringify` does not recognize a Map object as anything different than a regular object, and the JSON spec itself does not have a way to properly store a Map. It just treats the map as a regular object, possibly including any own object properties set on it.

```js
var m = new Map();

// This is not included:
m.set('test', 123);

// This would be included:
m['other'] = 456;

console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
```

If you are just using string keys, you could use a regular object instead of a Map.

Comment: I don't know how many hours I tried to debug my seemingly empty map. Turns out the data was always there. Any way to log map contents without looping through it?

Comment: @span Most console.log implementations will display the contents a Map. Otherwise, looping is your only option I think.

Comment: Thank you. Wow, that is really crappy. Why the heck can't a Map, the most natural object in the world, not be serialized into json...?

Answer (score 12):

**Basic solution :**

First if you have

```
const map = new Map();
```

and you set values this way :

```
map.set('key', 'value');
```

Object.stringify will emit and empty object.

You can fix that this way:

```
const objFromMap = Object.fromEntries(map);
JSON.stringify(objFromMap);
```

**Complex objects :**

If you have a map field into an object, example:

```
class MyClazz {
   field = new Map();
}
const instance = new MyClazz();
instance.field.set('k', 'v');
```

JSON.stringify will result :

```
{field: {}}
```

to fix that, override toJSON method. You'll have :

```
class MyClazz {
   field = new Map();
   toJSON(): this {
      return {
          field: Object.fromEntries(this.field),
      }
   }
}
const instance = new MyClazz();
instance.field.set('k', 'v');
```

Then, when using JSON.stringify(instance); we'll have :

```
{field: {k: 'v'}}
```

Answer (score 5):

With credit to Tim Brown in his [blog post](http://codebuckets.com/2018/06/17/extending-typescript-to-serialise-map-objects-to-json/) on the subject - when the contents of the Map object are serialisable, you can do:

1. serialise Map to JSON:

   `JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.entries()))`
2. de-serialise JSON to Map:

   `new Map(JSON.parse(jsonStr))`

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others Maps arent yet supported by JSON. However 2d arrays are so one can do:

```
const map1= new Map().set("one",1),
           map2 = new Map().set("two",2),
           concatMap = {
              one:[...map1],
              two:[...map2]
           };

const result = JSON.stringify(concatMap);
```

To parse that, do:

```
 let {one,two} = JSON.parse(result);
 one = new Map(one),
 two = new Map(two);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
const newMap = JSON.parse('{}');
newMap[name] = value;
```

and stingfy newMap. The result is pars as Map<string, string>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map1 = {"one", 1}` instead of map object.

Here's working plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/mUP5KbTVCo0JgdlqH1qQ?p=preview